# multidimensional , matrix array configuration

Tags: javascript, arrays

Something seems not right about this, it stops working as intended every now and then, am i missing something.

```
/*this is a test of a nameing system */

var name = ""; /* <-- if you put a name here it will be used instead of a the list of names*/

names = [ /*female names*/ ["ann", "chi", "sue", "sally", "tammy", "wowser"], /*male names*/ ["joe", "don", "bob"]];

var myname = ""; /*<-- multipurpose filler for later use also*/
var i = 0; /* <-- pre establised varible to stop out of scope errors */
var sex = 0; /* <-- put here to represent varible provided else where not included here*/

if (name !== "") {
    myname = name;
} else {
    if (sex === 0) {
        for (n = 0; n < names[0].length; n++) { /*<-- my solution to how large an array is*/
            if (names.length < 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        i = Math.floor((Math.random() * (n - 1 + 1)) + 1) - 1; /* my solution to not being able to randomly generate zero*/
        myname = names[sex][i];
    } else {
        for (n = 0; n < names[0].length; n++) { /*<-- my solution to how large an array is*/
            if (names.length < 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        i = Math.floor((Math.random() * (n - 1 + 1)) + 1) - 1; /* my solution to not being able to randomly generate zero*/
        myname = names[sex][i];
    }
}
alert(myname);
```

any guidance would be appreciated. (i pressed ctrl k, but it does not seem to be formatting correctly) it fixed itself after i posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`names[0]` is an array, so you can check its length with `names[0].length`.  Same goes for `names[1]`.  So assuming `sex` is 0 or 1:

```
if (name) {
    myname = name;
} else {
    myname = names[sex][Math.floor(Math.random() * names[sex].length)];
}
```